# Fosuserbundle login API (For Mobile app login)

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have username and password. Using Fosuserbundle - I require to check valid user or not. In web its working properly. I require API in that, suppose  I am passing username and password and its giving appropriate response.

i.e: username: xxxx
     password : xxxx

Answer (score 0):

If you need create an API I will recommend you read this https://gist.github.com/tjamps/11d617a4b318d65ca583

Basic RESTful API with Symfony 2 + FOSRestBundle (JSON format only) + FOSUserBundle + FOSOauthServerBundle.

The best way to authenticate your users in your Mobile app is using OAuht2 authentication.